# angularjs POST 405 method not allowed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth, satellizer, npm-live-server

I have an **angularjs** project that contains an oauth to github.

I use the [satellizer plugin](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) to deal with the oauth protocol.

Every time I try to connect I get this error:

[image]

Here is my route config (it's ES6 using Babel) :

```
export default function RouteConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

 $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: './modules/default/default.html',
        controller: 'DefaultController',
        controllerAs: 'default'
    })
    .when('/auth/:provider',{
        controller: 'OAuthController',
        templateUrl: './modules/auth/auth.html',
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}
```

I tested the app using Postman, all the GET requests work fine but every POST request returns a 405.

I use [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) to host my angularJS application. I've read that the issue might be server-related. How can I solve that ?

I also use **npm** to deal with the packages.

**EDIT : ** I tried with [simplehttpserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplehttpserver) here is what I got:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

well as it seems you do an http POST call somewhere in your application.
and you send this request to

```
http://localhost:8080/src/auth/callback
```

as it seems there is no server listening - or at least not to a POST request. probably you will have to find the http request in your code and check whether you're using the correct url for your request

Comment: The url is fine, I defined that path in my routeconfig and I am able to get the values using a GET request, I don't understand why the POST request is not allowed

Answer (score -1):

I finally figured out. AngularJS cannot deal with POST requests, it's the server responsibility to do that, I forgot to start and add code for the server.

For those who will have the same issue than me, examples are here:

https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples